# FLIP fluid simulation does not detect collisions anymore

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, collision

Sorry for such question, but someone is getting dumber by the second (me or blender): fluid collision stopped working completely (worked before by some miracle)

Domain is set, fluid set as Geometry, cube is set as Effector-Collision.

Collision does not stop liquid at all.

.blend file attached:

[image]

Comment: It seems that was an issue with effector. Surface Thickness was set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Here's even a more low-down on the collision objects interaction in a domain.  There are 4 "variables" to consider.  I have updated the dev team today where I think something along these lines should be hinted at in the documentation.  An object where there is no collision thickness will look the "most real", as opposed to seeing liquid that seems to collide with a "force field offset from the object".

1. If you have a "thick" collision object (like a cube) around minimum of z=0.15, then the collision will work with collision thickness=0
2. If you have a thin collision object (like a plane), you can add a Solidify modifier thickness >= 0.106, then the collision will work with collision thickness=0
3. If you have relatively lower Domain Resolution Division (e.g., 60) and a thin collision object (like a plane), you can set the collision thickness>=0.5 (approx).
4. You can reduce a thin collision object's collision thickness if you increase the Domain Resolution Division (e.g.>= 100) and/or decrease the Liquid Particle Radius to < 1.0

Unfortunately this is all an experimental approach that can cost many hours of iterative bake time.  You should start out with the minimum end-frame time that shows sufficient liquid interaction, and iteratively adjust some of these variables and re-bake.

Here is an example [image] file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for false alarm-question.

It seems that was an issue with effector(for some reason it was changed accidently). Effector's Surface Thickness was set to 0

Just now tried same file with reinstalled Blender, and changed only this option and collision worked.

Comment: Ah yes, i've found that for fluid I have to use a min thickness of 0.4 or 0.5.   This can then cause problems where it looks like the fluid never gets close enough the the surface, so I then have to compensate with a hidden, phantom object that is 0.5 (units?!) larger than the actual visual collision object.  I've reported this as a bug.